# Converting from ThreadPool to ProcessExecutorPool

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code which I would like to convert from using ThreadPool to use of ProcessPoolExecutor since it is all CPU intensive calculations and when i observe the CPU monitor I note that my 8 core processor is only using a single thread.

```
import datetime
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool


def thread_run(q, clients_credit_array, clients_terr_array,
               freq_small_list, freq_large_list, clients, year, admin):
    claim_id = []
    claim_client_id = []
    claim_company_id = []
    claim_year = []
    claim_type = []
    claim_closed = []
    claim_cnt = []
    claim_amount = []

    print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    i = 0
    client_cnt = 1000
    loop_incr = 8
    while i < client_cnt:
        ind_rng = range(i, min((i + loop_incr), (client_cnt)), 1)
        call_var = []
        for q in ind_rng:
            call_var.append((q,
                             clients_credit_array,
                             clients_terr_array,
                             freq_small_list,
                             freq_large_list,
                             clients,
                             year,
                             admin))

        pool = ThreadPool(len(call_var))
        results = pool.map(call_claim, call_var)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for result in results:
            if result[0] == []:
                pass
            else:
                r = 0
                if r < len(result[0]):
                    claim_index += 1
                    claim_id.append(claim_index)
                    claim_client_id.append(result[0][r])
                    claim_company_id.append(result[1][r])
                    claim_year.append(result[2][r])
                    claim_type.append(result[3][r])
                    claim_closed.append(result[4][r])
                    claim_cnt.append(result[5][r])
                    claim_amount.append(result[6][r])
                    r += 1
        i += loop_incr
    print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

The difficulty I am having, however, is that when I modify the code as follows, I get error messages:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PThreadPool
```

```
        pool = PThreadPool(max_workers=len(call_var))
        #pool = ThreadPool(len(call_var))
        results = pool.map(call_claim, call_var)
        #pool.close()
        #pool.join()
```

I had to remove the pool.close() and pool.join() as it generated errors.  But when I removed them, my code was not utilizing parallel processors and it ran much longer and slower than originally.  What am I missing?

Comment: And what if you replace join() and close() with context manager? It's safer, shorter and may behave a bit different (not sure about the last). Use `with PThreadPool(...) as pool:` `results = pool.map(...)`. I'm not sure if close and join are correct methods for ProcessPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, it is common to see `Executor` used as part of a context manager and without the need for `join` or `close` operations.  Below is a simplified example to illustrate the concepts.

Example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time
import os

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def times_two(n):
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 5))
    print("pid:", os.getpid())
    return n * 2


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(times_two, values)

        for one_result in results:
            print(one_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
pid: 396
pid: 8904
pid: 25440
pid: 20592
pid: 14636
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  I can only surmise then that the act of splitting my function calls is actually taking longer to process due to overhead involved (it's also faster with multiprocessor.dummy than it is with multiprocessor).